# Apache CXF JAX-RS service is missing XML document start

Tags: jax-ws, document, cxf, jax-rs

I am developing web services using Apache CXF and Spring. My interfaces and configuration are configured so that I have both REST and SOAP services.
Apache CXF is not putting the XML document start: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

For the SOAP service I implemented an interceptor and it works perfectly. Here's the code:

```java
public class CustomHeaderInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

public CustomHeaderInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.PRE_STREAM);
    addBefore(StaxOutInterceptor.class.getName());
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
    message.put(Message.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    message.put(StaxOutInterceptor.FORCE_START_DOCUMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
}
}
```

The interceptor is added with the following configuration:

```xml
<bean id="customHeader" class="com.minervanetworks.xtv.stb.utils.CustomHeaderInterceptor" />

<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logInbound" />
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="customHeader" />
        <ref bean="logOutbound" />
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
    <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logInbound" />
    </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
    <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logOutbound" />
    </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
</cxf:bus>
```

Unfortunately this does not work for my JAX-RS server. The "StaxOutInterceptor.FORCE_START_DOCUMENT" is processed by the StaxOutInterceptor and it is not in the chain when I'm using JAX-RS. It could not be added manually since it depends on StaxOutEndingInterceptor which is in the *ending phase and is called after JAXRSOutInterceptor.

I also tried implementing handler for the same purpose but without any success.

Here is my JAXRS server configuration:

```xml
<jaxrs:server id="restServer" address="/rest">
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="systemExceptionMapper" />
        <ref bean="jaxbProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        ...
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        <entry key="feed" value="application/atom+xml" />
        <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Any kind of help - ideas, suggestions, whatever will be appriciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of time invested in this problem, I found the following solution.

Apache CXF is not putting the XML Document Start when it is marshaling collections, which was my case. It is kind of omission in JAXBElement provider. I realized that everything is just fine when marshaling single objects.

So the obvious solution for me was to wrap my collection in a collection object, like this:

> public class CollectionWrapper{
>
> private List collection;
>
> ...
>
> }

Refactoring my methods to return CollectionWrapper, rather than List did the job.

Comment: +1 for sharing your solution with the community. You should also mark your own question as answer.